# Set same height on two absolute position elements

Tags: css

I want to set equal height on dropdown ul elements, but how? :)

Demo:

```
jsfiddle.net/DpA2L/
```

Hovering the options 3, 4 and 6 make the dropdowns that havent same height. Any ideas?

EDIT: I want this: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20442642/sce2.jpg

Comment: what do you want exactly?

Comment: You know that message that popped up saying "Links to JSFiddle must be accompanied with code"? <- that.

Comment: @murtaza I want to set same the height of lower element the same as the higher

Comment: @3rror404 That's why he formatted the link like code, causing me in turn to downvote the question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand your question correctly, but if you want to have your expanded menu have the same heights , the easiest way is to ensure you have the same amount of elements in it.

in example - your option 3 is

```
<li>
Option 3
<ul>      
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
<ul>     
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

and your option 4 is

```
<li>
Option 4
<ul>      
    <li class="noHover">Menu heading</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
<ul class="menuText">      
    <li class="noHover">Textfield heading</li>
    <li>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce lacus tortor, posuere sit amet nisl lobortis, luctus volutpat lorem. 
    </li>

</ul>
```

Try adding the  to your option 3 list, but without any text.
then be sure to position it the same way as the other ones, that have a 'menu heading'.
Like in your css.

```
#menu ul li ul {
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 48px;
(...)
}
```

Again - try asking your question more precisely - I don't know if I understood it right

Comment: Yes, but I want the same height with different number of items. This: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20442642/sce2.jpg

Answer (score 0):

add this to the CSS . You specified a height for it and it takes it always.

```
#menu ul {
text-align: left;
display: inline;
margin: 0;
padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
list-style: none;
max-height:300px;
height:300px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15); 
}
```